# Finding maximum from matrix : optimise way

Tags: c++, c

I want to find out maximum of number from this 5x5 matrix/array of size 25 .
I am using below trick .But I want to know any other way I can optimize this logic or any other logic is also welcome .Tagging c and cpp to get more coverage for this question .

```
//Dummy code :
#include <stdio.h>
inline int max_val(int x, int y)
{
    return (x > y)? x : y;
}
int main(){
int src[25] =  {19,26, 34, 48, 50 , 24, 95, 91, 54, 28,47, 45, 48, 68, 24 ,27, 10, 20, 28, 65 ,98, 96, 94, 92, 20};
/*  just showed as example
19 26 34 48 50  
24 95 91 54 28  
47 45 48 68 24  
27 10 20 28 65  
98 96 94 92 20  */

int dst[25]={0} ;//purposefully not initialised as it is dummy code
int width = 5;
int* pImage0 = src;
int* pImage1 = pImage0 + width;
int* pImage2 = pImage1 + width;
int* pImage3 = pImage2 + width;
int* pImage4 = pImage3 + width;
int BoxMax0,BoxMax1,BoxMax2,BoxMax3,BoxMax4,BoxMax;
for(int loop =0; loop<25;loop++){
    BoxMax0 = max_val((pImage0[0]),max_val((pImage0[1]),max_val((pImage0[2]),max_val(pImage0[3],pImage0[4]))));
    BoxMax1 = max_val((pImage1[0]),max_val((pImage1[1]),max_val((pImage1[2]),max_val(pImage1[3],pImage1[4]))));
    BoxMax2 = max_val((pImage2[0]),max_val((pImage2[1]),max_val((pImage2[2]),max_val(pImage2[3],pImage2[4]))));
    BoxMax3 = max_val((pImage3[0]),max_val((pImage3[1]),max_val((pImage3[2]),max_val(pImage3[3],pImage3[4]))));
    BoxMax4 = max_val((pImage4[0]),max_val((pImage4[1]),max_val((pImage4[2]),max_val(pImage4[3],pImage4[4]))));
    BoxMax  = max_val(BoxMax0,max_val(BoxMax1,max_val(BoxMax2,max_val(BoxMax3,BoxMax4)));
    pImage0++;
    pImage1++;
    pImage2++;
    pImage3++;
    pImage4++;
    dst[loop] = BoxMax;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should tag only c because the code looks like pure C. C and C++ are distinct languages. What compiler are you using, C or C++ compiler? Anyway, your code seems to have many issues. Why the loop if you calculate the maximum inside the loop? And why do you output into `dst[25]` as the maximum is a single number, not a matrix.

Comment: Please pick a language. In C++ you'd call [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and be done.

Comment: The loop unrolling will be close to optimum. The challenge will be to automate the code to accept different widths and unroll appropriately. I believe I have seen similar routines on the net. You might google `c find matrix max loop unroll` and see what comes back. Also, the compiler with optimize the ternary operator for you, so that should be fine.

Comment: The loop serves no purpose in this code and should be removed.

Comment: "Tagging c and cpp to get more coverage for this question." -- that's the true spirit of a spammer.

Comment: For one, the solutions might vary depending on whether you are programming in c++ or c. Second: have you actually tested whether the manual loop unrolling gives you any benefits compared to what the compiler would automatically generate?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what your code is supposed to do (especially as you are accessing memory locations outside of `src`), but I'd almost bet that

```
int max = *std::max_element(begin(src), end(src));
```

is actually faster than your construct.

Comment: what about float variable ??

Comment: @studionstru: Can you be a bit more specific? If you are asking whether this code will work for and arrray of doubles, then yes (just replace `int max`with `double max` or just use `auto max`